# Find transform matrix between two camera pose sets

Tags: computer-vision, matching

I have two cameras, A and B, bound together(i.e. their movement are same). Each camera records a set of poses which belong to SE(3). However, the timestamps of two camera are not aligned, even time interval are different.

How do I find the relationship between these two cameras(in transform matrix)? Can I use ICP by treating camera pose as 16-dimension point in space(I wonder that SO(3) part is not independent)?